# Can we conditionally hide "Help" menu options in Maximo start center?

Tags: maximo

Is it possible to hide help menu options conditionally in Maximo start center. I have tried by associating sigoption and condition to a help menu item in MENUS.xml but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which app was your sig option on?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think it makes sense to do this particularly since the Maximo help is available online anyway but that being said, if you're intent on going ahead with your requirement, one option is to use the help grid control in place of the help menu.

You could add help grid controls to the application screen(s) you wish to provide help for and set the HTML Content property of the control to some relevant help text then use the More Information property of the control to link to the Out of the Box help file, for example:

> com.ibm.mbs.doc,company/c_companies_application.html

You can get the appropriate text for the More Information property for the Help Grid control from the existing Application Help property value of the Application's Presentation properties.  By removing the Application Help property value the Help menu item for the application will no longer function.

The help grid control can also have a Signature Option and conditional properties.